# Pegar tamanho do ScrollPane quando definido pela ancoragem - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Eu tenho um ScrollPane ancorado nos 4 lados de um AnchorPane para que quando redimensionar a tela, o scroll também redimensione. Assim não preciso especificar um tamanho fixo. Até aí funciona como quero.

O problema é que desta forma os métodos `getPrefWidth()`, `getWidth()`, `getMinWidth()`, `getMaxWidth()` não me retornam o tamanho atual do scroll.

Alguém sabe como pegar o tamanho do ScrollPane defindo seu tamanho pela ancoragem e não pelos `sets` de definição de tamanho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [getBoundsInParent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent--) ou [getBoundsInLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInLocal--). São funções que calculam as dimensões do nó com base em suas coordenadas. Em seguida usar os métodos getHeight() e getWidth() (Ou outros que julgar apropriados).

**Exemplo:**

```
AnchorPane parent = new AnchorPane();
ScrollPane child = new ScrollPane();

AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(child, 10.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(child, 10.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(child, 10.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(child, 10.0);

parent.getChildren().add(child);

// Painel principal
Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 200, 200); 
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

System.out.println("Height: " + child.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()); // 180
System.out.println("Width: " + child.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()); //180
```

Referências: [Get the Dimension of a Node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997232)

Comment: Obrigado, Gustavo! Funcionou bem demais

Answer (score 0):

Para a barra vertical:

```
jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()
```

ou para a barra horizontal:

```
jScrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum()
```

Comment: Oi Rocigno. Na verdade os métodos que você sugeriu são para o scroll da biblioteca gráfica swing. No Javafx é diferente :\